# How to react to colleague refusing mentoring when it could actually help?

Tags: mentoring

I do have an small internal question as to my way of reacting at my current workplace.

We are small team with quite broadly defined roles, but with quite overlapping skills and competent members (or so I'd like to think). We are all technical members with a specific main skill though.

I have a more senior outlook on the code side of things and believe I can structure and express a technical vision of the project. I am weaker on other aspects too, but that is ok, to each his own. I also have measurable years of service in the IT world.

I do have a younger colleague, whom I know is competent, and whom insights I respect, but quite lacking in code quality and structure. He recently was struggling with an aspect of the code, quite ostensibly, and I happen to have implemented said aspect some time ago.

I noticed that and proposed some help. He firmly refused said help. It does happen often, and I believe he wants to impose himself, or at least he fears for his competence being put to question - which I do not intent to do, really. He ended up indeed struggling with the problem.

I do not want a small team going through power struggles. Now, I personally would like to help, I believe it brings the project further forward. It feels like the sensible, mature thing to do.

Now two things:

1. I can simply accept said situation and ignore that. Don't believe it is the best for the project
2. I should try to help in a more well meaning, subtle way

It is becoming clear that while he wants to learn, he is doing some harm to the project. It is not being noticed, nor do I want to make it go noticed: I respect the person and want to find a constructive solution.

I also recognize that this all comes down to authority in the end. I do have a boss I should mention, who is keen to keep everything flat and equal. I have already expressed that while I believe in dynamism and equality, there comes a time one should take some lead in specific aspects. I have suggested for equality that the boss should give a lead to each of the member in it own best competence. For now the boss has refused, fearing some reactions.

My question: is it ok to want to mentor, and if yes, is the way I tackle that mentoring correct ?

Comment: "*What advice would you give me *" That we can't tell you what to do. We *can* answer questions like "When does it make sense to do X?", "How do I accomplish Y?" or "What are the risks of Z?". I have to say though, what makes you think making everyone a (team?) lead position or fancy title would accomplish? Mentoring or training someone does not require having management authority over them.

Comment: I agree with Lilienthal, you question should be less open.

Comment: Ok good point, I will rephrase the question.

Answer (score 5):

Help is offered, not forced on people.

Him not accepting help isn't a problem.

But if he's "struggling with the problem" and "doing some harm to the project", that is a problem. It is, however, an entirely different problem. If your teammate is underperforming you offer your help. You already did that. Beyond that it's the boss's problem - who can only fix the problem if they're aware of it. You state you want to hide that problem from your boss, but I advise against it.

Comment: I realise reading the answer, which is actually full of good sense I will admit, that there is a point I should mention: the boss expects me to take care of technical mentoring. My problem is though, it hasn't be made official. I think these are murky waters.

Answer (score 3):

Focus on getting your job done before getting others done.

It's perfectly fine to be willing to help and its okay to offer help but don't enforce it if its not your call:

> Hey, I happened to be working on a similar problem as X a little back. Feel free to let me know if there's something I can do to help you, whether its answering some questions or helping with the implementation.

If he doesn't want help, there's not much you can do, and you shouldn't waste your energy, or make him annoyed by it, assuming that he's actually working on the problem.

If you truly begin to suspect that he's incapable of doing the task and that it affects the project in a negative way you need to raise that flag to your employer, make him aware of the issue and let him decide whether you are to be assigned to complete or help with the given task. You should only do this if you're certain your co-worker is unable to complete the task within the time-frame that he's been given.

Until then, let it be enough to have offered help, focus on your work and evaluate whether he really needs your help or not. Maybe he's slow, but that doesn't mean he won't get the job done in time.

Comment: Thank you. The problem here is not one of being slow or quick: that is only one metric by which to judge a solution quality. We do have a massively aging code base that is not being taken care of. I am expected to handle said aspect, and can only achieve this by making sure we all drive by the same quality standards. I do actually rate the solutions of said colleague, but usually not the maner in which these are achieved. Might it be that I am oversteppingM

Comment: If it's within your job description to handle something then by all means, handle it. If it's vague, clarify with your manager. Just make sure that there's actually a problem that needs to be solved and that its a part of your job to solve it. This is the best I can say with the information at hand. Good luck.

Comment: It actually is, having made it clear with the boss recently. The discussion has been enlightning, all the more ever since I notice said colleague shows reactions of big fear and nervosity. I can actually see quite through the behaviour, every help attempt is perceived as an attack and I can actually see the reactions days before they come. It is quite predictable really. I think no matter what, I should communicate to him that I am not looking to put him down, but to help. It is a nice exercise in the end, I am actually enjoying the psychological challenge. To me it's about working together